# MassTransit Transactional Outbox CleanUpInboxState faulted

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, masstransit

I've been trying to use the MassTransit Transactional Outbox in the last months. One problem that I'm having is that I keep getting this error that the CleanUpInboxState faulted:

> fail: MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration.BusOutboxDeliveryService[0]
> CleanUpInboxState faulted
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

I have more than 1 machine running the application, so I believe that this is happening because there are at least 2 machines trying to cleanup InboxState data at the same time. But I don't see a way to control and avoid this concurrency.

Any ideas? Is there any configuration I could use?

Comment: Are you on an older version? That exception was changed to DEBUG logging level at some point.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson So this exception should not cause any problems? I'm using v8.0.8